# Laravel Form dropdown with optgroup

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, select, optgroup

Let's say I have a collection with categories, while eager loading all descriptiones per category. So this means, each category `hasMany` descriptions. I want to display all descriptions in a dropdown, while the `optgroup label` is the category name, belonging to the description. So something like this:

```
{{ Form::select('description', ['' => 'Select'] + $descriptions) }}
```

And the results will be something like this (first google hit):

[Example](https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/html-select-optgroup.png)

I know I need to simply pass a multidimensional array, but I am not sure how to achieve that. Any pointers would be helpful. I know the following will give me an array of `Categories`:

```
Category::orderBy('name', 'asc')->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
```

But I cannot simply load the descriptions, since the following will produce the same attay, without any descriptions:

```
Category::with('descriptions')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load categories:

```
$categories = Category::with('descriptions')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```

Then prepare the `$descriptions` array:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $descriptions[$category->name] = $category->descriptions->pluck('name', 'id');
}
```

Comment: This would simply create multiple dropdowns, wouldn't it? But I need everything in one dropdown, with the category names being an optgroup label

Comment: @Hardist yes, since you have many categories. If you want to display all the descriptions in one dropdown, use the code from the updated answer.

Comment: Apologies, I know how to display a simple dropdown using a collection. But I want to display the category names as optgroup label, and for each optgroup (category) I want to display the description names. Right now I am doing it using a lot of foreach loops, but I don't want that

Comment: Seems to go in the right direction, but I cannot figure out how to display the data how I want in a dropdown. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Hardist as far as I remember, you should just put the array with this format `['group' => ['key' => 'item', 'key' => 'item']]` and Laravel Collective Form will build the dropdown with groups.

Comment: Thanks, will play around with it :) Much appreciated

Comment: Just came back to this question using google lol. Needed it again. Don't remember what I did last time, but this time I just added `->toArray()` like so:

`foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $descriptions[$category->name] = $category->descriptions->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
        }`

And that worked :)